# Retrieve Facebook Lead ID from pixel after user completes Lead Ad Form

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ads-api, facebook-pixel

We are running Lead Ad campaigns. Upon completion, we have a webhook that writes the lead to our CRM.

Additionally, we have a landing page they can go to to "Learn More" after they complete the lead form.

Is there a way to get the lead_id from the Facebook pixel and tracking code so I can attempt to connect that lead to the newly created record in the database? I basically want to know if I can get that lead_id from a web visitor who has actually completed a lead on our campaign via JS.

Comment: did you ever work this out?   I am struggling with the same issue.